# SQL query calculate and display sum data per each month of the year

Tags: mysql

I have 'orders' table with some data like the following:

```
---------------------------------
id     |   amount  |  order_date   
---------------------------------
1      |   100.00  |  2018-03-12
2      |   120.00  |  2018-03-25
3      |   200.00  |  2018-04-10
4      |   250.00  |  2018-04-20
5      |   300.00  |  2018-05-02
```

i want to display the SUM('amount') per each month in the current year, i want to use this data to create a chart later.

I want to achieve like this results.

```
---------------------------------
month        |   sum(amount)
---------------------------------
January      |   0.00  
February     |   0.00 
March        |   320.00 
April        |   450.00
Mai          |   300.00
June         |   0.00
July         |   0.00
August       |   0.00
September    |   0.00
October      |   0.00
November     |   0.00
December     |   0.00
```

I create a separate table 'months' containing all the months of the year then i left join 'orders' with it but it didn't work, this is the query i use.

Please help.

```
SELECT months.month, IFNULL( sum(orders.amount), 0 ) AS amount
FROM months
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON month(orders.order_date) = months.month
GROUP BY months.month
```

---

### update

Finally i made it work this is my query

```
SELECT IFNULL( sum(orders.amount), 0 ) AS amount
FROM months
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON monthName(orders.order_date) = months.month
GROUP BY months.month
Order BY FIELD(MONTH,'January','February','March','April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
```

Comment: Note that you will also need a condition in the ON clause for "in the current year".

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [month()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function returns a number, as opposed to the name of the month.

Either use the [monthname()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) function or store the months' number in your helper table as opposed to the name of the month. The latter is slightly more reliable, since the language setting of mysql influences the return value of the monthname() function.

Comment: Thanks, monthname() worked for me, i have one more issue, since the month are in text format i can't get the ORDER BY to work perfectly is there any way to fix this, i want the result to start from January ... to December

Comment: If you have any follow- up questions, then pls post them as a new question with proper explanation as to what you have tried and what error you encountered.

Comment: @IdilassiJassi the question should also be marked as solved by accepting the answer, that solved the original one, not anything *after* the fact.

Comment: the answer i got from @Shadow solved half of the question, that's why i didn't consider it as a final solution

Comment: I updated my question with the final solution, thank you @Shadow for your help

Comment: @IdilassiJassi I answered the question fully. Any follow up questions should be asked separately. You must not keep asking for frther and further details in comments.